# How to solve linker error "LIBCURL.LIB contains invalid OMF record, type 0x21 (possibly COFF) " in C++Builder?

Tags: c++, curl, c++builder, libcurl, c++builder-xe

I am getting a linker error while trying to use libcurl in Embarcadero C++ Builder XE:

> [ILINK32 Error] Error: 'C:...\CURL-7.52.1\BUILD\WIN32\VC8\DLL RELEASE\LIBCURL.LIB' contains invalid OMF record, type 0x21 (possibly COFF)

I have built the `curl-7.52.1` library in Visual Studio 2005.

I am able to get `libcurl.dll` and `libcurl.lib` after building.

I tried a sample project in VS 2005 and I am able to execute it.

But I want to use libcurl in C++Builder instead.

If I use the same library built in VS 2005 in my C++Builder project, it is giving me the linker error.

Can you please help me?  How can I use the libcurl library in my C++Builder project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++Builder's `.lib` file format (OMF) is different from MS Visual Studio's format (COFF).  You should be able to make a compatible `.lib` file from the DLL using C++Builder's [`IMPLIB` command-line utility](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Implib):

```
implib.exe -a LIBCURL_BCB.LIB LIBCURL.DLL
```

And then add this `LIBCURL_BCB.LIB` file to your project **instead of** the `.lib` file you got when compiling `libcurl` in VC++.

The `-a` switch is used to generate underscores for `__cdecl` functions.

On my computer, I have only C++Builder 5, and its `implib.exe` is found in this folder:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Borland\CBuilder5\Bin\

Comment: I Copy DLL and then run command given by you:::::::                     C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\bin>implib.exe LIBCURL_BCB.lib libcurl.dll                                                                    .     

CodeGear Implib Version 3.2.0 Copyright (c) 1991-2009 CodeGear
Fatal error LIBCURL_BCB.lib: unable to open output file

Comment: @PratikMota you are probably in readonly directory. Change dir to your project.

Comment: @n.m.  Yes I have taken implib in different folder and tried. It Created New Library..............  BUT Still some Linking Error...  Project property--> Directoryed and Condition 
Include PAth:-  C:\.....\LIBCURLDemo\curl-7.52.1\include
Library Path:-  C:\....\LIBCURLDemo\curl-7.52.1\build\Win32\VC8\DLL Release

Also i have added library in project and removed "Linked by Name Only"
=================

But still it is giving Linker Error

[ILINK32 Error] Error: Unresolved external '_curl_global_init' referenced from C:\....\SOURCE\APPLICATION\OBJ\NEWFILE.OBJ
...etc.How to resolve it ?

Comment: libcurl.lib  (15KB)
New created using implib.exe, libcurl_bcb.lib ( 7KB )   ,Is there any Issue ??

Comment: @borisbn  Woow... Very nice.. It works. Really Thank you very much..!!

Comment: @n.m.  Thank you very much for your answer also.